# Alterntives to BEM syntax that comply with WordPress coding standards?

Tags: theme-development, css

I'm interested in using [BEM (Block-Element-Modifier) syntax](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) with my WordPress theme development, but underscores in class names violate [WordPress coding standards](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/css/). BEM is awesome because it makes the stylesheet easier to understand what it's modifying and reduces cascading style issues. But I also want to play by the rules. What is a good alternative to underscores?

Comment: This may not be the best place to ask as it's open to many answers. A better place may be Google WordPress Groups or the [WordPress forums](https://wordpress.org/support/). That being said if you plan on contributing to WordPress Core I would stick to the standards. If it's a project outside core development then look at the WordPress Coding Standards like Pirates Code - they're more like guidelines really. Do whatever you think is best for your project.

Comment: Upvoted as I like the question – and closed as it's just the wrong place.

Comment: The actual syntactic sugar of BEM is fairly pointless, you can just use hyphens for everything and get the same point across, the human brain is very good at interpreting words if you make them meaningful. Most of the use cases of BEM can be handled by adhering to a grammar instead of awkward characters. Check out SMACSS for examples of how adopting a grammar can be just as clear, and far more natural feeling (generally leading to much more rapid development).